# Specified hdfs ip in pyhdfs.HdfsClient, but it show my hostname

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, pyhdfs-client

Just like this:

```
hdfs_client = HdfsClient(hosts='10.1.103.49:50070')

root_files = hdfs_client.listdir('/')
print(root_files)
hdfs_client.copy_from_local('./Readme.md', '/image/Readme.md')
```

it can print root_files successfully, but copy_from_local cannot run.
The error info is

```
HTTPConnectionPool(host='ubuntu-ms-7d25', port=50075): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/image/Readme.md?op=CREATE&user.name=zzz&namenoderpcaddress=10.1.103.49:9000&overwrite=false&user.name=zzz (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fe3d8c157b0>: Failed to resolve 'ubuntu-ms-7d25' ([Errno -2] Name or service not known)"))
```

I even don't know where "ubuntu-ms-7d25" come from, my hadoop conf files doesn't have this hostname.

So I want to know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Datanodes automatically associate their hostnames to the namenode